How to generate asset previews in Blender using Python opening a .blend files?
I recently created new Blender files for each asset I've downloaded and added them to the correct catalog using a Python script. However, I am still missing one feature: generating previews for these assets.
I attempted to use the following command in my script to generate the previews:
bpy.ops.ed.lib_id_generate_preview().
But the context was incorrect when this operator was called after using bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile() to load the Blender file.
Is there an alternative method to automatically refresh or generate previews for assets in Blender? I considered using a shell script that would open the Blender file and execute a Python script using the --python-expr option. Would that work, or is there a more effective way to handle this?

Hello, you should use the bpy.types.ID member asset_generate_preview instead. See https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.asset_generate_preview eg bpy.data.objects["Cube"].asset_generate_preview() Do note you need to wait for a little bit for the preview to actually render, if you're using a batch method and you close the file directly after generating the preview it will be blank upon re-loading the asset metadata

Hint : when a preview is generating bpy.app.is_job_running("RENDER_PREVIEW"): will be True
